# Transcribe addon & XML sitemap

Tags: multi-language, transcribe

I'd like to make a template that generates an XML sitemap for my multilanguage site (using Transcribe addon) that contains all entries in all languages. The site structure is just simple flat pages like so:

```
/en/page1-english
/en/page2-english
/de/page1-german
/de/page2-german
```

I tried this code and it works apart from the exp:transcribe:uri tag only gives me a link for the default language. How can I get transcribe to give me links for all entries in all languages?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
{exp:channel:entries channel="not products"  transcribe="disable" dynamic="no"}
<url>
<loc>
{exp:transcribe:uri path="{url_title}"}
</loc></url>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I worked it out by myself in the end...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
{!--Homepage--}
<url>
  <loc>{site_url}</loc>
</url>
{exp:query sql="SELECT l.abbreviation, t.url_title, c.channel_name FROM exp_channel_titles t 
inner join exp_channels c using (channel_id)
inner join exp_transcribe_entries_languages el using (entry_id) 
inner join  `exp_transcribe_languages` l on l.id = el.language_id
where t.status='open' and c.channel_name<>'products'"}
<url>
{if channel_name=='home_page'}
  <loc>{site_url}/{abbreviation}</loc>
{if:else}
  <loc>{site_url}/{abbreviation}/{url_title}</loc>
{/if}
</url>
{/exp:query}
</urlset>
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post your solution :) I'm sure this will help someone else in future.